The number of triangles with no common side in a polygon
Given an n-sided polygon, where n > 2, how many triangles can be made by joining the vertices of the polygon, such that none of the triangle’s side is one of the polygon’s side?
My first idea was to take the total number of triangles inside, then subtract it by the number of triangles that have at least one side that is a side of the polygon:
$$
\binom{n}{3}-n\cdot2\cdot(n-2)
$$
However, when I plugged 6 into this formula, I got something that wasn't the actual number of triangles satisfying the problem, I was expecting 2.
Then, I tried to count the triangles with 2 sides that are the polygon’s side, and the triangles with only 1 sides that is the polygon’s side.
$$
\binom{n}{3}-n-\frac{2n(n-4)}{3!}
$$
This still didn’t give me the expected answer of 2 when I plugged in 6, however, when I changed the 3! to a 2!, I did get the expected result, for both 5 and 6 sided polygons.
This was also the answer in this post:
Triangles with no common side in a polygon
However, I still don’t understand why the first approach didn’t work, and why the 3! had to be a 2!, my thought was that I choose 1 vertices, which had n choices, then choose the 2 neighboring vertices, with 2 choices, then choose the remaining vertices that aren’t neighboring the 2 chosen vertices, which is (n-4), and since I’m choosing 3 vertices, shouldn’t dividing them by 3! be the correct answer?

For a hexagon, shouldn't the answer be 6? I can find 6 possible triangles that can be formed by all the diagonals of a hexagon

@Gwen: for a hexagon, the long diagonals cannot be used, leaving the two triangles using short diagonals

Short diagonals? @Henry I'm sorry but by long diagonal do you mean the diagonal to the point exactly opposite to it? Like to the 3rd adjacent point?

@Gwen: Yes: five lines come from each point, one to the opposite point (long diagonal), two to immediately adjacent points (sides of the hexagon) and two to the remaining points (short diagonals).  If you use a long diagonal, the third point of the triangle will be adjacent to one of the points of the long diagonal and a side of the hexagon will be used.

One of your errors is the multiplication by $2$ in both your approaches. Your first approach has some double-counting issues too.
Essentially your question is about how many triangles use at least one side of the polygon. For $n \ge 4$:

clearly there are $n$ triangles which use exactly two polygon sides, as you say
to use exactly one polygon side, the polygon has $n$ sides, so taking one of these sides and its two ends, there are $n-4$ possibilities for the remaining triangle vertex  (neither of the two ends of the side nor their immediate neighbours): you considered $2n(n-4)/3!$ and  $2n(n-4)/2!$ and it is the latter which I would have written directly as $n(n-4)$; whatever caused you to write the initial $2$ needs to be divided out.

So the answer is $${n \choose 3}-n-n(n-4) =\frac{n(n-4)(n-5)}{6}$$

Quick sanity check: for $n = 6$ this gives 2 (the two equilateral triangles) and for $n = 7$ this gives 7 (there's one equivalence class of such triangles but it exists in seven orientations)

You are repeating cases when you choose a vertice and one from it's 2 neighbours
Case 1
Suppose you chose vertice A and one of it's neighbour B
Case 2
You choose vertice B and it's neighbour A
Both are the same cases but on applying 2n(n-4), we are counting them differently
